# Linux: Detect 64-bit kernel (long mode) from 32-bit user mode program

Tags: linux, kernel, 32-bit, mode

What's the best and most reliable way to detect if a 32-bit user mode program is running on a 64-bit kernel or not (i.e. if the system is in 'long mode')? I'd rather not call external programs if possible (or have to load any kernel modules).

Note: I want to detect whether a 64-bit kernel is being used (or really, whether the CPU is in long mode), not simply if a 64-bit capable processor is present (`/proc/cpuinfo` tells me that but not whether the 64-bit capability is being used).

The kernel fakes a 32-bit processor if `uname` is compiled 32-bit or if `setarch i686` is used.

Comment: You could look at e.g. `/proc/vmallocinfo` and see if addresses are 32 or 64 bit

Comment: That can only be read by root, right?

Comment: `/proc/kallsyms` is an alternative that is default world-readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the `uname()` function and check the returned `machine` string, which will be `x86_64` for a 64-bit Intel platform.

One way of reversing the effect of the use of `setarch` is to reset the personality:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <sys/personality.h>

int main()
{
    struct utsname u;

    personality(PER_LINUX);

    uname(&u);
    puts(u.machine);
    return 0;
}
```

This shows the right results when compiled in 32-bit mode and run on a 64-bit system:

```
$ gcc -m32 -o u u.c
$ ./u
x86_64
$ setarch i686 ./u
x86_64
```

EDIT: Fixed code to reverse effect of `setarch`.

[Reference](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname).

Comment: This sort of works, but if I run the program with `setarch`, i.e. `setarch i686 ./uname` it prints i686 instead.

Comment: That's correct behaviour though, isn't it?  You are explicitly changing the architecture that the process is seeing.

Comment: Well what I'm really trying to do is find out if the CPU is in long mode or not.

Comment: @atomice: Well, the CPU isn't in long mode while it's running your 32 bit process...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that uname() is cheating, there are still several mechanisms. One way is to check the width of the address of any of the kernel symbols.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *inputline = malloc(1024);
  char *oinputline = inputline;
  int fd = open("/proc/kallsyms", O_RDONLY);
  int numnibbles = 0;
  if (fd == -1) {
      perror("open");
      free(inputline);
      exit(1);
  }
  read(fd, inputline, 1024);
  close(fd);
  while(!isspace(*inputline)) {
      numnibbles++;
      inputline++;
  }
  printf("%dbit\n", numnibbles*4);
  free(oinputline);
  exit (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel is configured for it, you can read the kernel config from /proc/config.gz

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_64BIT
# CONFIG_64BIT is not set
```

I'm not sure how portable you need it to be- it doesn't seem like a super common config option.